# Jstor Web Scraping Returning Empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jstor

I am trying to datascrape article titles from Jstor. However, I keep getting an empty return. [Here is an example of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEXsx.png) that I want to scrape, with my goal being to return the highlighted line that says "Lower Court Reactions to Supreme Court Decisions: A Quantitative Examination". When I run my code however, I get nothing every time. What's wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main1= "https://www.jstor.org/stable/i310437"
page = requests.get(main1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.findAll('span', class_="show-for-sr")

for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Comment: You're receiving an empty list because HTTP get request is coming back with a 420 status code response. Even trying to do a HTTP get request on JSTOR home page does this. I suspect they're imploying tactics to stop scrapers. I'm pretty sure Aaron Swartz was web scraping this website.... You can imagine after that they'll be taking web scraping pretty seriously.

Comment: Looking at the HTML via simulating a browser (using the selenium package), shows this <!-- ERROR: Page Loading Error generated via Fastly Servers -->
<h2>Page Loading Error*</h2>
<p>We are unable to process your request at this time.</p>. So possible there's an error at the JSTOR servers..

Comment: No no... You just have to make a correct get request

Answer (score 0):

You have to add user-agent to get required information:

```
.......
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
}

......
page = requests.get(main1, headers=headers)
......
```

Example of Output:

```
Volume Information
Front Matter
Note: Presidential Coattails Revisted
Oiling the Tax Committees in Congress, 1900-1974: Subgovernment Theory, the Overrepresentation Hypothesis, and the Oil Depletion Allowance
A Test of the Revolving Door Hypothesis at the FCC
Mao's Concept of Representation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send User-Agent in the headers i recommend to do it in a session to:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.jstor.org', headers=headers)
r = s.get('https://www.jstor.org/stable/i310437', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
titles = soup.select('.show-for-sr')
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Volume Information
Front Matter
Note: Presidential Coattails Revisted
Oiling the Tax Committees in Congress, 1900-1974: Subgovernment Theory, the Overrepresentation Hypothesis, and the Oil Depletion Allowance
A Test of the Revolving Door Hypothesis at the FCC
Mao's Concept of Representation
The Mass Public and Macroeconomic Performance: The Dynamics of Public Opinion Toward Unemployment and Inflation
Assessing the Candidate Preference Function
Another Look at the Life Cycle and Political Participation
Stratification and the Dimensions of American Political Orientations
Lower Court Reactions to Supreme Court Decisions: A Quantitative Examination
What They Don't Know Can Hurt You
Interpreting Heteroscedasticity
Back Matter
```

Note you need to have lxml installed for this code.

```
pip install lxml
```

If you not already have it installed.